# Skip language packs in Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, language-pack

Windows Update has 31 optional language packs in the Windows 7 Professional updates. They are unchecked and will not be installed. It is a bit annoying that there is a large list of updates totalling about one gigabyte that I obviously don't need.

How can I tell Windows Update: "No, thank you, skip these updates"? If someday I need to test a software with a different localization I would like to be able to reactivate formerly skipped updates. This skipped updates list feature had been available in Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

To "skip" an update, right-click the update's line, and then select "Hide update".  Then that update will no longer be shown.

You can later unhide these updates ("restore hidden updates" in the left-column menu) if you change your mind.